# How to substitute function errors with NA output in R?

Tags: r, error-handling

Is there an elegant way to force the execution of a function and return a `NA` consistent with its normal output type if any error is encountered?

For example, to have `lm` batch process data in R, and pick just a single estimate, avoiding stop on errors using `tryCatch`:

```
lmCoeff <- function(beta, ...) { 
  tryCatch(ifelse(is.numeric(a <- lm(...)$coefficient[beta]), a, as.numeric(NA)), 
           error = function(e) {
             return(as.numeric(NA))
           } )
}

# test with 3 cases
(good <- lmCoeff(beta="cyl", mpg ~ cyl, mtcars))
(bad  <- lmCoeff(beta="bad", mpg ~ cyl, mtcars))
(ugly <- lmCoeff(beta="cyl", ugly))

# output should always be of the same type:
str(good)
str(bad)
str(ugly)
```

The question is whether there a more elegant and less idiosyncratic way to do this.

Comment: I think this is the only way to do it.

Comment: This is the correct way to do it, AFAIK.

Comment: note that the idiosyncrasy is not the use of `tryCatch`, but the need to use a nested `ifelse` statement, and manually figure out what is the output type.

Comment: I guess it boils down to `errNa <- function(func, ...) { as.numeric(tryCatch(func(...), error = function(e) return(NA)) }`

Answer (score 1):

As stated, `tryCatch` can be used to catch all errors and output an `NA` of numeric type if any error is found. In the case where you know what errors are to be expected, then you could directly check for them using a `if` statement.

For example, I can think of two possible errors: user enters invalid data object, or the formula is not valid. So a neater (and imo more responsible solution) would be:

```
lmCoeff <- function(beta, ...) { 

    if(<data does not exist>){
        a <- NA
        warning("data not found")
    } else if (<formula invalid>){
        a <- NA
        warning("formula invalid")
    } else {
        lapply(..., function(x) print(str(x))))
        a <- lm(...)$coefficient[beta] 
    }

    as.numeric(a)

}
```

}

Of course in practice if it is too complicated to write conditions to check that the data does not exist, or the formula is invalid, then for simplicity you can use `tryCatch`.

Comment: Using `if` to prevent anticipated errors makes sense. But is there a way to fool-proof an `lm` call (or any other) against unforeseeable errors, while maintaining output consistency? It may be useful, for example, when such functions are called from within `data.table` or `dplyr::summarise`.

Comment: `tryCatch` is the only way to full proof it, however, I think it is better to first catch any expected errors first, so that you can warn the user.